# Plotting multivariable integration

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

If I have a multivariable integration like

```
NIntegrate[x^2 + y^2, {x, 1, 5}, {y, 6, 10}]
```

But I need to plot its result in terms of `x` . Then how to do it ?

Comment: The result of the integration is a constant independent of `x,y` ?

Comment: What you have there is a constant...

Comment: Do you mean something like `With[{int = Integrate[x^2 + y^2, {y, 6, 10}, {x, 0, t}]}, 
 Plot[int, {t, 0, 10}]]`?

Comment: Exactly !!! Thanks man! Trying that @R.M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would be your answer :

```
data = Integrate[x^2 + y^2, {x, 0, t}, {y, 6, 10}];
Plot[data, {t, 0, 6}]
```

and this would be your Graphic :

[image]

Answer (score 8):

DSaad's answer above is correct. You can use symbolic integration to get the formula. The solution when using numeric integration (`NIntegrate` instead of `Integrate`) can be more complicated. You have to be careful about the order of evaluation. In earlier versions of Mathematica, you had to use `?NumericQ` to delay the evaluation of the numeric integral:

```
myFunction[t_?NumericQ]:= NIntegrate[x^2 + y^2, {x, 0, t}, {y, 6, 10}]; 
Plot[myFunction[t], {t, 0, 6}]
```

To see why `?NumericQ` is needed here, please see [this](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12502) ([original version](https://web.archive.org/web/20140709133301/http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3820)). Using `?NumericQ` is a still a good idea. It helps your function to behave consistently and makes your code more predictable.

Comment: I assume you meant `NIntegrate`, not `Integrate` in the definition of `myFunction`?

Comment: yes. Sorry about that.

Comment: Please see my answer.  Perhaps it is better, if you agree that `NumericQ` is no longer necessary, that you update your answer and I delete mine.  I think it would make this Q&A more coherent.

Comment: I think NumericQ still really should be used in this case. The function could easily be used in other contexts and it's behavior should be consistent. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

*[Background: I added this answer because this question was cited in     [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) as an example of when `NumericQ` was required.  I took the integrand to be a simple example of a more general problem with `NIntegrate`, but on reading the comments, it seems to be narrowly the exact integrand of interest to the OP.  I recall a time when plotting functions would complain about numeric issues, but I could not test this specific case. It was also intended to offset [Searke's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/144/searke) answer, which I take was necessary back in '12. But perhaps this so well known that this answer is of little value, and I should remove the part of the [pitfalls answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) that implies `NumericQ` is useful in such cases as this and delete this answer.]*

As of at least V9 and after, you do not need to protect the function with `NumericQ` when using `Plot`:

```
Plot[NIntegrate[x^2 + y^2, {x, 0, t}, {y, 6, 10}], {t, 0, 6}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Aside: This is true for `ParametricPlot` in V9, too, but not in V10.2. 
In V10.2, you get a single warning message:

```
 ParametricPlot[{t, NIntegrate[x^2 + y^2, {x, 0, t}, {y, 6, 10}]}, {t, 0, 6}, AspectRatio -> 0.6]
```

> NIntegrate::nlim: x = t is not a valid limit of integration. >>

But the plot is generated correctly:

[image: Mathematica graphics]