# How can I get plot

Tags: plotting, variable

here I want to plot the v vs p ...the code I used here...

```
Clear["Global`*"]

p'[v] = (((c1^2 + c2^2 + u*v)*(v + u)*v)/(d1^2*(v^2 - c1^2)*p*
   v)) + ((d1^2*
   p^2 (v^2 + c1^2 + (v^2 - c1^2)^2/2*c2^2))/(d1^2*(v^2 - c1^2)*p*
   v));
p1 = Integrate[p'[v], v];
```

now what should I do get the plot v vs  p1....

Comment: See [Plot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html?q=Plot)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting multivariable integration](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9891/plotting-multivariable-integration)

Comment: Can't get any plot or particular procedure to get that plot .. #zentient

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: The first thing you must do is to associate values to parameters For instance you can

Comment: "Can't get any plot or particular procedure to get that plot..." -- You'll get more traction on the site, if you post what you tried. Others are probably going to assume you made a simple mistake. -- Site usage tip: Use @user instead of #user to notify a user of your response.

Comment: add to that you should include actual error messages you get from what you tried.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the undefined variables:

```
pp[v_, c1_, c2_, u_, d1_, 
   p_] := (((c1^2 + c2^2 + u*v)*(v + u)*v)/(d1^2*(v^2 - c1^2)*p*
       v)) + ((d1^2*
       p^2 (v^2 + c1^2 + (v^2 - c1^2)^2/2*c2^2))/(d1^2*(v^2 - c1^2)*p*
       v));
p1[c1_, c2_, u_, d1_, p_] := Integrate[pp[v, c1, c2, u, d1, p], v]
```

Then you can plot the function for any range of the variables:

```
Plot[Evaluate[p1[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], {v, 0, 1}]
```

[image]